# Loop code to screen multiple stocks

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using the following code to identify the stocks that have experienced growth for the past 6 months.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AMZN")
monthly_stock<-to.monthly(AMZN)
adx <- ADX(HLC(monthly_stock), n = 14, maType = "EMA", wilder = TRUE)[, c("DIp", "DIn", "ADX")]
adx$DIp-adx$DIn[(nrow(adx)-5):nrow(adx),]>10
```

The output is

```
Jul 2015 TRUE
Aug 2015 TRUE
Sep 2015 TRUE
Oct 2015 TRUE
Nov 2015 TRUE
Dec 2015 TRUE
```

But I do it "manually" for each stock. I want to automate the process so that I load multiple stocks at once

```
stocklist<-c("AMZN","GOOG","AAPL","FB","TSLA") 
getSymbols(stocklist)
```

And out of these downloaded stocks, I want to filter out those that satisfy these criteria ("TRUE" for the past 6 months) like I did above. Any suggestions how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would layout the code along the following lines:

```
stock.list = c("AMZN","GOOG","AAPL","FB")
res = list()
for(ss in stock.list) {
     stock.data = getSymbols(ss, from="1900-01-01", auto.assign=F)
     monthly.data = to.monthly(stock.data)
     adx = ADX(HLC(monthly.data),n=14,maType="EMA",wilder=TRUE)[,c("DIp","DIn","ADX")]
     monthly.adx = adx$DIp-adx$DIn[(nrow(adx)-5):nrow(adx),]>10
     if(all(as.logical(monthly.adx[,1]))) {
        res[[ss]] = monthly.adx
     }
}
# res is a list.
# names(res) gives you the stock symbols for the interesting stocks
# res[["AMZN"]] contains the data - the adx for the last six months in this case
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to incorporate my above code within yours but can't do batch conversion to monthly display `to.monthly(ss)`

Comment: `ss` is the ticker, aka "AMZN". `to.monthly` takes time series. if the data goes into the list res, and you need monthly series for "AMZN", then `res[[ss]] = to.monthly(stock.data)`.

Comment: thanks, and looks like it should be working bur for some reason when I run the code I get this error `Error in EMA(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  : n > number of non-NA values in column(s) 1`

Comment: Something goes wrong in the `ADX...` call for the GOOG ticker (works fine for AMZN). The docs are probably the best place to start.

Comment: is there a way to automatically "reject" such stock which contain NA's because, when screening large amount of stocks, it will happen to some other stocks as well and it will kill the entire attempt. Instead, is it possible to make the code "get over it" and simply not select it in the final list?

Comment: I solved the issue by using `na.omit`, replacing `stock.data = getSymbols(ss, from="1900-01-01", auto.assign=F)` with `stock.data = na.omit(getSymbols(ss, from="1900-01-01", auto.assign=F))` what do you think?

Comment: If this is part of a real life application, I'd try to find the root cause - something seems fishy - why are the NAs generated in the first place? If they are expected, then probably ADX has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `diff` function.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AMZN")
monthly_stock<-to.monthly(AMZN)
adx <- ADX(HLC(monthly_stock), n = 14, maType = "EMA", wilder = TRUE)[, c("DIp", "DIn", "ADX")]
adx$DIp-adx$DIn[(nrow(adx)-5):nrow(adx),]>10

adx <- tail(adx, 7)
adx.res <- sapply(1:ncol(adx), function(x){
  y <- diff(as.vector(adx[, x]))
  if (all(y>0)) {
    return(x)
  }
})

names(adx)[unlist(adx.res)]
# ADX
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I don't quite get how the input should be accomplised. I imagined something like `stocklist<-c("AMZN","GOOG","AAPL","FB")` followed by `getSymbols(stocklist)` This gets the stock data loaded but I cannot plug this into your code.

Comment: You may want to make your question more clear. We are not familiar with economics or stocks.

Comment: I rephrased the question, essentially I am trying to work on a list of stocks to do what I did to AMZN, and filter out only the ones who satisfy the criteria ("TRUE" for the past 6 months).